# Reinforced.Typings generates declare enum instead of export enum

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm using *Reinforced.Typings* library to generate TypeScript models from my C# Dtos. I'm facing an issue where enums are generated as `declare enum` instead of `export enum`, e.g.

```
declare enum MyEnum {
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1
}
```

Whereas I would like to have it as

```
export enum MyEnum {
    Zero = 0,
    One = 1
}
```

Configuration uses Fluent API and roughly consists of

```
config.Global(configBuilder => configBuilder.DontWriteWarningComment().UseModules());

// substituations (omitted for the sake of brevity)
config.Substitute(typeof(MyType), new RtSimpleTypeName("string[]"));

// using reflection get all dtoTypes by convention and register
config.ExportAsInterfaces(dtoTypes, conf => conf.WithPublicProperties());

config.ExportAsEnum<MyEnum>();
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce this in a smaller application to share here.
Can someone help to understand what can cause this behavior ?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6, *Reinforced.Typings* version 1.6.1